# Problema com label em cima dos gráficos no ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartjs

Estou usando o ChartJs e o StackedBar para criar alguns gráficos, porém, o ChartJs não tem opção de colocar os respectivos valores em cima das barras, para isso, implementei a seguinte solução:

```
    onAnimationComplete: function() {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
        ctx.fontSize = '14px';
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        this.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function(bar) {
                ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y + 15);
            });
        });
    }
```

Porém, quando passa o mouse em cima dos gráficos, os valores somem como demonstrado no Fiddle abaixo:

https://jsfiddle.net/bspe1w2q/

Alguém consegue me ajudar a fazer com que os valores não sumam ao passar o mouse?

Comment: acabou que eu consegui resolvendo alterando o próprio cor do plugin, eliminando o código que fazia os textos desaparecerem ao passar o mouse, foi a única solução que consegui encontrar

Comment: Boa tarde Caio. Poderia mostrar como ficou o código com a solução?